# Checking JSON file contains valid fields using jsonschema

Tags: python, json, jsonschema

I have ongoing issues with data being missing from a JSON file after an API call. I have captured both good and bad JSON files that have been returned. I am trying to check if the JSON file that is returned contains the fields I am after.

```
import json
import jsonschema

def validateJson(data):
 try:
    jsonschema.validate(instance=data, schema=good_schema)
 except jsonschema.exceptions.ValidationError as err:
    return False
 return True

# schema to check against
good_schema = {
 "type": "object",
 "properties": {
     "vac1": {"type": "number"},
     "SOC": {"type": "number"},
     "pdisCharge1": {"type": "number"},
     "ppv": {"type": "number"},
     "pLocalLoad": {"type": "number"},
     "chargePower": {"type": "number"},
 },
# "required": ["vac1", "SOC", "pdisCharge1", "ppv", "pLocalLoad", "chargePower"]
}

f = open(r'C:\Users\david\PycharmProjects\JSON_TEST\test.json')
data = json.load(f)
isValid = validateJson(data)
if isValid:
    print(data)
    print("Given JSON data is Valid")
else:
    print(data)
    print("Given JSON data is InValid")
```

The above returns

C:\Users\david\PycharmProjects\WebScrap\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/david/PycharmProjects/JSON_TEST/main.py
{}
Given JSON data is Valid

Process finished with exit code 0

Clearly the file being checked does not contain the items.

If I use "required": ["vac1", "SOC", "pdisCharge1", "ppv", "pLocalLoad", "chargePower"] then I get

C:\Users\david\PycharmProjects\WebScrap\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/david/PycharmProjects/JSON_TEST/main.py
{}
Given JSON data is InValid

Process finished with exit code 0

Which appears to be correct but once I load a valid file then I get

C:\Users\david\PycharmProjects\WebScrap\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/david/PycharmProjects/JSON_TEST/main.py
{'332761': {'devices': {'NTCIA13017': {'statusData': {'pdisCharge1': 0.34, 'vac1': '244.1', 'SOC': '60', 'ppv': 0, 'pLocalLoad': 0.34, 'chargePower': 0}}}}}
Given JSON data is InValid

Process finished with exit code 0

I am thinking that my good_schema is not correctly defined to look for the 6 fields I need. The JSON file is very large and is nested to 5 levels. This is what test.json contains.

```
{
 "332761": {
  "devices": {
   "NTCIA13017": {
    "statusData": {
     "pdisCharge1": 0.34,
     "vac1": "244.1",
     "SOC": "60",
     "ppv": 0,
     "pLocalLoad": 0.34,
     "chargePower": 0
    }
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Any ideas?

EDIT

Additional code based on suggested solution below.

```
good_schema = {
 "type": "object",
 "additionalProperties": {
  "type": "object",
  "required": ["devices"],
  "properties": {
    "devices": {
      "type": "object",
      "additionalProperties": {
        "type": "object",
        "required": ["NTCIA13017"],
        "properties": {
          "NTCIA13017": {
            "type": "object",
            "additionalProperties": {
              "type": "object",
              "required": ["statusData"],
                "properties": {
                  "statusData": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "required": ["vac1", "SOC", "pdisCharge1", "ppv", "pLocalLoad", "chargePower"],
                      "properties": {
                      "vac1": {"type": "number"},
                      "SOC": {"type": "number"},
                      "pdisCharge1": {"type": "number"},
                      "ppv": {"type": "number"},
                      "pLocalLoad": {"type": "number"},
                      "chargePower": {"type": "number"}
}}}}}}}}}}}
```

This fails on 'NTCIA13017' is a required property

Comment: You are discarding an exception that may contain valuable info and instead return a simple `false`. Let the exception propagate up the stack and, especially for such a small example, you get the stack trace for the whole thing. Also, please extract a [mcve] so people can reproduce your problem and use that as a base to suggest a solution.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the comments. I have checked and err.message returns 'vac1' is a required property
{'332761': {'devices': {'NTCIA13017': {'statusData': {'pdisCharge1': 0.34, 'vac1': '244.1', 'SOC': '60', 'ppv': 0, 'pLocalLoad': 0.34, 'chargePower': 0}}}}}
Given JSON data is InValid
I understand what minimal reproducible example means but as I have copied the entire code then I don't else I could include?

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying that the data

`{'332761': {'devices': {'NTCIA13017': {'statusData': {'pdisCharge1': 0.34, 'vac1': '244.1', 'SOC': '60', 'ppv': 0, 'pLocalLoad': 0.34, 'chargePower': 0}}}}}`

isn't succesfully evaluating against the json schema

```
{
 "type": "object",
 "properties": {
     "vac1": {"type": "number"},
     "SOC": {"type": "number"},
     "pdisCharge1": {"type": "number"},
     "ppv": {"type": "number"},
     "pLocalLoad": {"type": "number"},
     "chargePower": {"type": "number"},
 },
 "required": ["vac1", "SOC", "pdisCharge1", "ppv", "pLocalLoad", "chargePower"]
}
```

? Because that's not surprising at all. Your data is nested several levels deep, but the schema is asking for the properties to be at the top level.

You need to specify the proper expected location for the data fields:

```
"type": "object",
"additionalProperties": {
  "type": "object",
  "required": ["devices"],
  "properties": {
    "devices": {
      "type": "object",
      "additionalProperties": {
        "type": "object",
        "required": ["vac1", "SOC", "pdisCharge1", "ppv", "pLocalLoad", "chargePower"],
        "properties": {
          "vac1": {"type": "number"},
          "SOC": {"type": "number"},
          "pdisCharge1": {"type": "number"},
          "ppv": {"type": "number"},
          "pLocalLoad": {"type": "number"},
          "chargePower": {"type": "number"}
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Read more about how to structure schemas for object types here:  https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/object.html

Comment: Thanks Ether, I have tried your code above but it fails on "vac1". I also tried to extend the referencing to the lower levels to see if that helped. But it didn't. See above for edit to question with additional code.

Comment: Read the error message carefully. You have one too many levels in your schema, so the "NTCIA13017" property is being taken up by "additionalProperties" under "devices". You need to move that `"required": ["NTCIA13017"]` and `"properties": { "NTCIA13017":...` up one level.